# Site too wide on both iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, css

Can anyone tell me why the following site renders really wide on an iPhone? It's been restricted it to 950px wide and the height has been specified a bottom margin incase the page was too short.

[image: redletterdaysforbusiness.co.uk at time of question.]

http://redletterdaysforbusiness.co.uk

Comment: You do realize that the device in your screenshot is significantly narrower than 950px, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you set the viewport size? Perhaps you could try this. Place it in the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
```

Comment: Is this tuned for the iPhone? I tried using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> but that did not work. Is there another way to make it responsive to the screen size of the device?

Comment: Use content="width=1200" the way I have it above. You may have to change 1200 to less or more depending on the size of you site but this will make your site appear as it does on an iPhone as it does on your browser.

Comment: On Twitter Bootstrap, <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200"> does in fact work for my page on an iPhone and iPad where <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> did not! Thanks @Michael!